# yii2 dynamic form inserting data in one model only

Tags: yii2

I'm trying to incorporate wbraganca dynamic form in yii2. But it's inserting data in only bills table(equivalent to the customer table) but not in productsales table(equivalent to address table). I'm not getting where the error is. There's no error in the console. After hitting the create button the page goes blank with a white screen. I can see data inserted in the bills table but not in productsales table. 
_form.php in bills -

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use kartik\form\ActiveForm;
use dosamigos\datepicker\DatePicker;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use kartik\select2\Select2;
use yii\helpers\Json;
use yii\web\View;
use frontend\modules\invoice\models\Parties;
use frontend\modules\invoice\models\Productbatch;
use frontend\modules\invoice\models\Year;
use frontend\modules\invoice\models\Console;
use wbraganca\dynamicform\DynamicFormWidget;
use kartik\depdrop\DepDrop;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model frontend\modules\invoice\models\Bills */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="bills-form">
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id' => 'dynamic-form', 
        'type' => ActiveForm::TYPE_HORIZONTAL,
        'formConfig' => ['labelSpan' => 3, 'deviceSize' => ActiveForm::SIZE_SMALL]
    ]); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-lg-9">
                <?= $form->field($model, 'bills_partyname')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Parties::find()->orderBy(['parties_partyname' => SORT_ASC,])->all(),'parties_partyname','partyDetails'),
                'language' => 'en',
                'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Party Name', 'id' => 'partyid'],
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'allowClear' => true
                ],
                ]); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                <?= $form->field($model, 'transport')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">

                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'bills_year')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                        'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Year::find()->orderBy(['yid' => SORT_DESC,])->all(),'year_year','year_year'),
                        'language' => 'en',
                        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Year', 'id' => 'yearid'],
                        'pluginOptions' => [
                            'allowClear' => true
                        ],
                        ]); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'console')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                        'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Console::find()->orderBy(['consoleid' => SORT_ASC,])->all(),'console','console'),
                        'language' => 'en',
                        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Console','id' => 'consoleid'],
                        'pluginOptions' => [
                            'allowClear' => true
                        ],
                        ]); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'billno')->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'readOnly'=>true]) ?>
                    </div>



            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                <?= $form->field($model, 'billdate')->widget(
                    DatePicker::className(), [
                    // inline too, not bad
                     'inline' => false, 
                     // modify template for custom rendering
                    //'template' => '<div class="well well-sm" style="background-color: #fff; width:250px">{input}</div>',
                    'clientOptions' => [
                        'autoclose' => true,
                        'todayHighlight' => true,
                        'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
                    ]
                    ]);?>
            </div>
        </div>

            <?= $form->field($model, 'bills_ebillid')->textInput()->hiddenInput()->label(false) ?>
            <?= $form->field($model, 'num')->textInput()->hiddenInput()->label(false) ?>   
    </div>



    <div class="row">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h4><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i> Products</h4></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
             <?php DynamicFormWidget::begin([
                'widgetContainer' => 'dynamicform_wrapper', // required: only alphanumeric characters plus "_" [A-Za-z0-9_]
                'widgetBody' => '.container-items', // required: css class selector
                'widgetItem' => '.item', // required: css class
                'limit' => 20, // the maximum times, an element can be cloned (default 999)
                'min' => 1, // 0 or 1 (default 1)
                'insertButton' => '.add-item', // css class
                'deleteButton' => '.remove-item', // css class
                'model' => $modelsProductsales[0],
                'formId' => 'dynamic-form',
                'formFields' => [
                    //'itemid',
                    'productname',
                    //'batchno',
                    // 'expdate',
                    // 'mrp',
                    // 'rate',
                    // 'qty',
                    // 'free',
                    // 'total',                   
                    // 'discount',


                ],
            ]); ?>

            <div class="container-items"><!-- widgetContainer -->
            <?php foreach ($modelsProductsales as $i => $modelsProductsales): ?>
                <div class="item panel panel-default"><!-- widgetBody -->
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title pull-left">Products</h3>
                        <div class="pull-right">
                            <button type="button" class="add-item btn btn-success btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
                            <button type="button" class="remove-item btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <?php
                            // necessary for update action.
                            if (! $modelsProductsales->isNewRecord) {
                                echo Html::activeHiddenInput($modelsProductsales, "[{$i}]id");
                            }
                        ?>

                        <div class="row-fluid">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                                    <?= $form->field($modelsProductsales, "[{$i}]productname")->label(false)->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'placeholder' => 'Productname']) ?>                                   
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1 nopadding">
                                    <?= $form->field($modelsProductsales, "[{$i}]batchno")->label(false)->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'placeholder' => 'Batchno']) ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1 nopadding" >
                                    <?= $form->field($modelsProductsales, "[{$i}]expdate")->label(false)->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'placeholder' => 'ExpDate']) ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1 nopadding">
                                    <?= $form->field($modelsProductsales, "[{$i}]mrp")->label(false)->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'placeholder' => 'MRP']) ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1 nopadding">
                                    <?= $form->field($modelsProductsales, "[{$i}]rate")->label(false)->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'placeholder' => 'Rate']) ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1 nopadding">
                                    <?= $form->field($modelsProductsales, "[{$i}]qty")->label(false)->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'placeholder' => 'Qty']) ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1 nopadding">
                                    <?= $form->field($modelsProductsales, "[{$i}]free")->label(false)->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'placeholder' => 'Free']) ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1 nopadding">
                                    <?= $form->field($modelsProductsales, "[{$i}]discount")->label(false)->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'placeholder' => 'Discount']) ?>
                                </div>                                                               
                            </div> 


                            <?= $form->field($modelsProductsales, "[{$i}]itemid")->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
                            <?= $form->field($modelsProductsales, "[{$i}]total")->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
                        </div><!-- .row -->

                    </div>
                </div><!-- item panel default -->
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div><!-- container item -->
            <?php DynamicFormWidget::end(); ?>
        </div><!-- panel body -->
        </div><!-- panel default -->
    </div><!-- outer row -->

    <?= $form->field($model, 'billamount')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'overdue')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'cst')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'wbst')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'caseno')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'amount')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'discount')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'tot')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'surcharge')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'total')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'tax')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'mrpvalue')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'cstpercent')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'wbstpercent')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'surpercent')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'totpercent')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'transport')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>

<?php
/* start getting the transportdata */
$script = <<< JS
$('#partyid').change(function(){   
    var partyid = $(this).val();

     $.get('index.php?r=invoice/bills/get-for-party',{ partyid : partyid }, function(data){
        //alert(data);
        var data = $.parseJSON(data);
        $('#bills-transport').attr('value',data.transport);
    });
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
/* end getting the transportdata */
?>

<?php
/* start getting the ebilid */
$script = <<<EOD
  $(window).load(function(){
  $.get('index.php?r=invoice/bills/get-for-ebillid',{ ebillid : 1 }, function(data){
      //alert(data);
      var data = $.parseJSON(data);
      $('#bills-bills_ebillid').attr('value',data.ebillid);
  }
  );
});
EOD;
$this->registerJs($script);
/*end getting the ebillid */
?>



<?php
/* start getting the num */
$script = <<< JS
$(function(){
    $('#yearid').change(function(){   
        getNum();
    });
    $('#consoleid').change(function(){   
        getNum();
    });

    var yearid = $(this).val();
    var consoleid = $(this).val();

    var getNum = function(){
        var yearid = String($('#yearid').val());
        var consoleid = String($('#consoleid').val());
        $.get('index.php?r=invoice/bills/get-for-num',{ yearid : yearid, consoleid : consoleid }, function(data){
        //alert(data);
        var data = $.parseJSON(data);
        var getNum = data;
        $('#bills-num').val(getNum["num"]);
        });

    } ;

});
JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
/* end getting the num */
?>

<?php
/* start getting the billno */
$script = <<< JS
$(function(){
    $('#yearid').change(function(){   
        getBillno();
    });
    $('#consoleid').change(function(){   
        getBillno();
    });

    var yearid = $(this).val();
    var consoleid = $(this).val();

    var getBillno = function(){
        var yearid = String($('#yearid').val());
        var consoleid = String($('#consoleid').val());
        $.get('index.php?r=invoice/bills/get-for-billno',{ yearid : yearid, consoleid : consoleid }, function(data){
        //alert(data);
        var data = $.parseJSON(data);
        var getBillno = data;
        $('#bills-billno').val(getBillno["billno"]);
        });

    } ;
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
/* end getting the billno */
?>
```

BillsController

```
<?php

namespace frontend\modules\invoice\controllers;

use Yii;
use frontend\modules\invoice\models\Bills;
use frontend\modules\invoice\models\BillsSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use frontend\modules\invoice\models\Parties;
use frontend\modules\invoice\models\Productsales;
use frontend\modules\invoice\models\Productbatch;
use frontend\modules\invoice\models\Model;
use yii\helpers\Json;

/**
 * BillsController implements the CRUD actions for Bills model.
 */
class BillsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all Bills models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new BillsSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single Bills model.
     * @param string $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Bills model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Bills();
        $modelsProductsales = [new Productsales];

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

            $modelsProductsales = Model::createMultiple(Productsales::classname());
            Model::loadMultiple($modelsProductsales, Yii::$app->request->post());

            // validate all models
            $valid = $model->validate();
            $valid = Model::validateMultiple($modelsProductsales) && $valid;

            if ($valid) {
                $transaction = \Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
                try {
                    if ($flag = $model->save(false)) {
                        foreach ($modelsProductsales as $modelProductsales) {
                            $modelProductsales->productsales_ebillid = $model->bills_ebillid;
                            $modelProductsales->year = $model->bills_year;
                            $modelProductsales->console = $model->console;
                            $modelProductsales->billno = $model->billno;
                            $modelProductsales->billdate = $model->billdate;
                            $modelProductsales->productsales_partyname = $model->bills_partyname;

                            if (! ($flag = $modelProductsales->save(false))) {
                                $transaction->rollBack();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if ($flag) {
                        $transaction->commit();
                        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
                    }
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $transaction->rollBack();
                }
            }
        }
            //return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->billid]);
        else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
                'modelsProductsales' => (empty($modelsProductsales)) ? [new Productsales] : $modelsProductsales
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing Bills model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param string $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->billid]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing Bills model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param string $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    public function actionGetForParty($partyid)
    {
        $party = Parties::find()->where(['parties_partyname'=>$partyid])->asArray()->one();
        //$bottle -> select(['productnames.productnames_productname','productnames.bottletype','bottlename.unitprice'])->from('Productnames')->leftJoin('bottlename','productnames.bottletype = bottlename.bottlename')->where(['productnames_productname'=>$catid])->limit(1);
        echo Json::encode($party);
    }

    public function actionGetForEbillid($ebillid)
    {
        $ebillidvar = Bills::find()->select('(max(bills_ebillid) + 1) as ebillid')->asArray()->one();
        echo Json::encode($ebillidvar);
    }
    public function actionGetForNum($yearid , $consoleid)
    {
        $num = Bills::find()->select('(max(num) + 1) as num')->where(['bills_year'=>$yearid])->andWhere(['console'=>$consoleid])->asArray()->one();
        echo Json::encode($num);
    }

    public function actionGetForItemid($productid , $batchid)
    {
        $item = Productbatch::find()->select('max(itemid) as itemid')->where(['productname'=>$productid])->andWhere(['batchno'=>$batchid])->asArray()->one();
        echo Json::encode($item);
    }

    public function actionGetForBillno($yearid , $consoleid)
    {
        if($consoleid == 'GM1' || $consoleid == 'GM2'){
            $num = Bills::find()->select(['concat("GM/",(max(num) + 1)) as billno'])->where(['bills_year'=>$yearid])->andWhere(['console'=>$consoleid])->asArray()->one();
            echo Json::encode($num);
        }elseif($consoleid == 'SM1' || $consoleid == 'SM2'){
            $num = Bills::find()->select(['concat("SM/",(max(num) + 1)) as billno'])->where(['bills_year'=>$yearid])->andWhere(['console'=>$consoleid])->asArray()->one();
            echo Json::encode($num);
        }elseif($consoleid == 'CN'){
            $num = Bills::find()->select(['concat("CM/",(max(num) + 1)) as billno'])->where(['bills_year'=>$yearid])->andWhere(['console'=>$consoleid])->asArray()->one();
            echo Json::encode($num);
        }

    }

    public function actionSubcat() {
    $out = [];
    if (isset($_POST['depdrop_parents'])) {
        $parents = $_POST['depdrop_parents'];
        if ($parents != null) {
            $cat_id = $parents[0];
            $out = Productbatch::getBatchNo($cat_id);
            echo Json::encode($out);
            // the getSubCatList function will query the database based on the
            // cat_id and return an array like below:
            // [
            //    ['id'=>'<sub-cat-id-1>', 'name'=>'<sub-cat-name1>'],
            //    ['id'=>'<sub-cat_id_2>', 'name'=>'<sub-cat-name2>']
            // ]
            //echo Json::encode(['output'=>$out, 'selected'=>'']);
            return;
        }
    }
    echo Json::encode(['output'=>'', 'selected'=>'']);
    }
    /**
     * Finds the Bills model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param string $id
     * @return Bills the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Bills::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
    }
}
```

Create.php

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;


/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model frontend\modules\invoice\models\Bills */

$this->title = 'Create Bills';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Bills', 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="bills-create">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <?= $this->render('_form', [
        'model' => $model,
        'modelsProductsales' => $modelsProductsales,
    ]) ?>

</div>
```

Model.php

```
<?php

namespace frontend\modules\invoice\models;

use Yii;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

class Model extends \yii\base\Model
{
    /**
     * Creates and populates a set of models.
     *
     * @param string $modelClass
     * @param array $multipleModels
     * @return array
     */
    public static function createMultiple($modelClass, $multipleModels = [])
    {
        $model    = new $modelClass;
        $formName = $model->formName();
        $post     = Yii::$app->request->post($formName);
        $models   = [];

        if (! empty($multipleModels)) {
            $keys = array_keys(ArrayHelper::map($multipleModels, 'id', 'id'));
            $multipleModels = array_combine($keys, $multipleModels);
        }

        if ($post && is_array($post)) {
            foreach ($post as $i => $item) {
                if (isset($item['id']) && !empty($item['id']) && isset($multipleModels[$item['id']])) {
                    $models[] = $multipleModels[$item['id']];
                } else {
                    $models[] = new $modelClass;
                }
            }
        }

        unset($model, $formName, $post);

        return $models;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any errors in frontend/runtime/logs/app.log?

Comment: No errors in app.log

Comment: What about server logs? Like Apache if you use it.

Comment: Don't see any log entry regarding this issue in apache logs

Comment: I tried to update wbraganca dynamic form through composer but there was nothing to update

Comment: No idea how to help with this. Maybe use xdebug or just plain old die(); in different lines to see where it crashes.

Comment: Do you see anything wrong with the codes?

Comment: It looks ok. I'm not sure about `[{$i}]productname`. Is it proper? Usually arrayed field gets brackets at the end.

Comment: This should be ok. In the extention demo it's shown like this.

Comment: Hi.Did your problem solve?

Comment: No Sir. Still struggling.

Comment: Sorry Everyone.. I've found out the issue. The validation checking was not allowing data to be inserted in the productsales table. I've made some changes in the rule section in productsales Model and it's working fine now. Thank you everyone for your support.